# VintaSoft Imaging .NET SDK 11.0 with asp.net core api 5.0 give me swagger internal error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using VintaSoft Imaging .NET SDK 11.0 with asp.net core api 5.0
Copy Vintasoft.Shared.dll, Vintasoft.Imaging.dll, Vintasoft.Imaging.Pdf.dll, Vintasoft.Imaging.Annotation.dll, Vintasoft.Imaging.Annotation.Pdf.dll, Vintasoft.Imaging.Office.OpenXml, Vintasoft.Shared.Web.dll, Vintasoft.Imaging.Web.Services.dll, Vintasoft.Imaging.Annotation.Web.Services.dll, Vintasoft.Imaging.AspNetCore.ApiControllers.dll and Vintasoft.Imaging.Annotation.AspNetCore.ApiControllers.dll assemblies from "\VintaSoft Imaging .NET v11.0\Bin\DotNet5\AnyCPU" directory to the "Bin" directory of ASP.NET Core  and add references to assemblies in ASP.NET Core Web application.

Only when A0dding Vintasoft.Imaging.AspNetCore.ApiControllers.dll and Vintasoft.Imaging.Annotation.AspNetCore.ApiControllers.dll
Swagger give me internal Error 500
how solve this problem

Comment: In your asp.net core api 5.0 project, did you copy some dll files to your project's Bin directory causing a 500 error inside Swagger? Can you provide your code?

Answer (score 0):

Internal server error 500 means that error occurs on the server side. All server errors are saved in the server event logs. Please open event logs in your Windows server and try to find information about error.

If you have problem, which is related with VintaSoft Imaging .NET SDK, and you cannot solve the problem by yourself, please write about your problem to VintaSoft support team at support@vintasoft.com

Best regards, Alexander

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).